# Issue with join and 2 exact column names

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Never came across this before...

```
SELECT ".TBL_USERS.".username, 
       ".TBL_USERS.".id,  <-----------|
       ".TBL_COMMENTS.".creator,      |
       ".TBL_COMMENTS.".comment,      |- same column name
       ".TBL_COMMENTS.".date,         |
       ".TBL_COMMENTS.".id  <---------|
```

As you can see, I am selecting two id columns...  When i take them in PHP:

```
$userid = $row['id'];
```

How will I be able to realize which one is which?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a column alias, with `AS` keyword:

**Example:**

```
(id) AS id1.........(id) AS id2
```

Now from your query result, you can get them like this:

```
$userid1 = $row['id1'];
$userid2 = $row['id2'];
```

**More Info:**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 3):

This is one reason why ID is poor choice for an ID column.  You will have to alias your column names to know which is which.

Comment: heh - I thought of "Intelligent Design" when I read "ID"... =)

Answer (score 1):

USe `AS` to rename one of the `ID` column in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Remember... "AS" is not required for mysql, you can...

```
SELECT ".TBL_USERS.".username, 
       ".TBL_USERS.".id id1,  <-----------|
       ".TBL_COMMENTS.".creator,      |
       ".TBL_COMMENTS.".comment,      |- same column name
       ".TBL_COMMENTS.".date,         |
       ".TBL_COMMENTS.".id id2 <----------|
```

Comment: Thankyou for this, for other types of SQL it is required then?

Comment: I am not sure if other types of SQL requires "AS", It would be good if somebody else will help us.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered virtually the same question several times in the past:

- [PHP MySQL mysql_fetch_assoc with array keys distinguished by 'as' designations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552367/php-mysql-mysql-fetch-assoc-with-array-keys-distinguished-by-as-designations/3552391#3552391)
- [Merging result from 2 columns with same name and not over-writing one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358387/merging-result-from-2-columns-with-same-name-and-not-over-writing-one/3358411#3358411)
- [Php pdo result of JOIN query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380691/php-pdo-result-of-join-query/1380732#1380732)